# Change URL Route Name ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I've made a typo while creating the controller class of my web application and now my URL looks like this: /**Blogs**/postname.
And i wanted it to look like this: /**Blog**/postname or better yet /**blog**/postname.

I tried `RegisterRoutes` in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        "BlogPage",
        "blog/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Blogs", action = "Index", id = "" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
       "Default",
       "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       new { controller = "Blogs", action = "Index", id = "" }
   );
}

protected void Application_Start()
{
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

But when i try to navigate to `localhost:######/blog` I get a 404 error.
Is there a way to fix this without having to start all over again?

Comment: You can just change the name of the controller.  Visual Studio has built in rename/refactoring...

Comment: If I remember my routes correctly, both of those routes require the id parameter.  I think need to set `id = UrlParameter.Optional` if you want to be able to use just `\controller` in your url

Comment: @maccettura Can you please explain how to do this? And tell me if this will change de URL route to?

Comment: Thanks @Dave, i changed that but still get the 404.

Comment: When you use the `{}` syntax in your route, the strings in the urls are automatically converted to controllers/actions/etc.  So if you change your BlogsController to BlogController, and users enter Blog (or blog) in their URLs, MVC will automatically send them to BlogController.  

I recommend reviewing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Comment: @Dave, i tried renaming the controller, but, as i expected, i got dozens of exceptions, because of all other files that reference that controller. So it would be easier to just start all over again if my only option is going that route.

Comment: Visual Studio should give you a ligbulb that will let you refactor everything else, although you'll need to change anything in cshtml files manually.  But no, you don't need to start over.  Creating a new route will work, you just need to figure out the correct settings.

Comment: @Dave,Thanks mate! Problem solved! I changed the name of the controller to BlogController, clicked yes in the Visual Studio's lightbulb as you said, and at first it didn't work but then i changed the Views folder from Blogs to Blog, and now everything is working fine. But i still don't understand what i did wrong in the routing settings, i will keep trying figuring that out.

Answer (score 2):

Well from your posted routes I see that controller name is `Blogs` as seen in below posted code but you are trying to access it as `blog` then shouldn't it throw 404 (*Resource Not Found*)?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "BlogPage",
    "blog/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Blogs", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

Comment: Yes, exactly as @Dave said, the routes are the same because i want to replace the /Blogs with /blog.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do /blog/postname then you don't need {action} in the url at all.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "BlogPage",
    "blog/{postname}",
    new { controller = "Blogs", action = "Index", postname = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Your index action will look something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string postname = "") 
{
    if(postname == "") 
    {
        // show list of posts or some other content
    } else {
        // find content from postname and show that
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot believe that was something so simple (I'm even a little bit ashamed that took me so much time to find what i was doing wrong), but i finally did!

I was adding the code to `Global.asax.cs` - as said in my question and in this [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs).

But the correct way, or at least the way that worked, was adding the exact same code to `RouteConfig.cs` file.

So, **the answer is to add the exact same code in my question to the `RouteConfig.cs` file, and not to the `Global.asax.cs`.**